# Centroid in British National Grid

Tags: qgis, polygon, centroids, united-kingdom

I am trying to work out centroid of a polygon, but I need this in British National Grid.

Does anyone know a way of getting it to work in QGIS 3.10?

Comment: Trying to work out a way to get the centroid of a polygon and show it as a BNG value rather than in XY. I know it will need doing in field calculator.

Comment: What is the coordinate system of your data?

Comment: 27700 so is BNG.

Comment: have got the current code to work, but not happy with the fact that I have to enter the OS grid square manually.



concat ('NH') ||(right(left(x($geometry),4),3)) || right(left(y($geometry),4),3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need [my **experimental** QGis plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/osgb-plugin/version/0.1/download/) which gives you the `gridSquare` function to use in labels etc. The first argument controls how many digits you get from 100 giving `TF` to .001 giving TF3928703326.

[image]

Comment: Ian, will give that a go, really useful.

Comment: Ian, just tried it and works perfectly. thank you.

Comment: Is there a way it could be altered to allow for 12 figures, the government has a habit of wanting the grid square then 10 figures after.

Comment: So TF3928703326 - you set the size parameter to 0.001 for that (I don't support the TF3928703326SW format but if you need raise an issue on the plugin)